# How to unsort an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check status codes of domains, in order to not put to much burden on remote servers I want make sure there is enough time between requests.

For this I need to unsort an associative array (id:url) and

> generate a queue like this:  domain a, domain b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c, a...

I tried the following, cycle through the domains and check if the very domain has been requested in the last 3 iterations, continue with next domain and put this one to the end of the cycle.

```
$urls_last_checked = array();
foreach ($check as $id => $url) {

    // let's only monitor the last x urls with processed
    // save domain to array in order to avoid to many requests to this URL in a short period of time
    $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    // only continue with this domain if not checked before
    if (in_array($domain, $urls_last_checked)){ // we processed it before continue with next one
        echoerror ($domain." passed \n", $logfile);
        unset($check[$id]);
        $check[$id] = $url;
        continue;
    }
    else{
        // add this domain to array
        $urls_last_checked[] = $domain;
        // remove oldest domain we checked
        if (count($urls_last_checked) > 3)  array_shift($urls_last_checked);
        echoerror (print_r($urls_last_checked).$domain." added \n", $logfile);
    }
}
```

This unfortunately does not work, as the for loop will end and not consider the new array elements I added.

How can I make sure the foreloop continues or achieve my goal in a different manner?

Comment: How do you intend to handle the situation when there is one domain left to check? With the algorithm you described it gonna be infinite loop

Comment: Good question. Maybe I have to rethink on how to do it. At the moment I sleep for 2s, and continue to ensure not to much burden. In the end I want to use that 2 s to check for another domain in the meentime.

Comment: you may put all your domains in a priority queue, with last check time as a key - that will allow you at every iteration to get least recent domain.

Comment: good idea, but does not work in this case. The datasets are imported and if an import gets 1000 new datasets, they will have the same timestamp. Excactly the problem I am trying to overcome.

Comment: Could you explain, what `unset($check[$id]); $check[$id] = $url;` does? As far as I can see, let's say id is 1, won't that unset the element at offset 1 and then again set it, thus changing nothing.

Comment: This will basically put the key:value pair to the end of the array. Inended to unsort it, the problem is, that it will eventually just shift it. There must be a better way to create the queue with domains in an unsorted order like: a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c.